# How can I separate access within a network?

Tags: networking, privacy, limited-access

I am struggling to find a 'rule' in my router that separates access to different wired computers.

I have fibre coming into the building that links via Ethernet cable to a zyxel router. From this I have Ethernet to an 8 port switch which on turn attaches 4 computers and 2 printers together with full shared access to all systems attached to it.

What I want is to put in a second router/ switch that can have up to 5 other devices attached wired to it. Problem is I don't want these other devices to be able to access the original computers on the network OR be able to use the 2 printers.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a Firewall. A firewall is really a function. Now, a router can have firewall functionality, but to see if that is the case, you should mention the model of router, and you and others can check the manual of that router and see if it is possible. If it doesn't and it may not, then you could get a Firewall appliance or a router that has that functionality. A firewall would let you set rules like block incoming and/or outgoing connections to this range of ip addresses.

Also, particular recommendations are unpopular here, or popular but not accepted, they call it "shopping". But, you could try asking in the chat for what people use/suggest.

Comment: Personally, I don't know which models are good, as I don't have one, so I won't recommend any specific make/model unless necessary... and you could always check reviews.. and perhaps avoid a make you've had bad experiences with.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways of solving this problem - One would be

Internet 
    |
   Xyxel
    |
    +---  New Network PC1
    |
    +---  New Network PC 2.5 ... (You may need a switch for more ports)
    |
    +------ (wan) Ethernet Router
                    |
                   8 Port Switch
                    |
                    +----- (lan) Printer 
                    |
                    +----- (lan) Printer 2
                    |
                    +----- (lan) Existing PC 1 ...

This will allow your existing network to access the devices of the new network, but not the other way around, assuming the Ethernet Router is configured to do NAT.  Note that you will have to ensure the LAN IP addressess for the Ethernet router are in a different subnet to the IP Addresses handed out by the Xyxel.  (If the Xyxel hands out 192.168.x.x, you could set the Ethernet Router up to use 172.16.x.x).   There is a minor issue you need to be aware of of "double NAT", which might cause problems with some obscure protcols.

A "Better" solution requires 2 ethernet routers and might look as follows:

```
                  Internet
                    |
                  XYXEL Router
                    +      +
       -------------+      +------------------------
       |                                           |
 Ethernet Router 1                             Ethernet Router 2
 |                                              |
 |---  Printer 1                                |--- New PC1
 |---  Printer 2                                |--- New PC2
 |---  (rest of old network)                    |--- New PC3...
```

You may need a switch or 2 to extend the number of ports available on the ethernet router(s) - just make sure you don't run a cable between Ethernet Router 1 and Ethernet Router 2.

This second solution is a "better" solution then the first as it does not require double nat, and is more secure (ie separate zones).    You need to be mindful that the IP range on the LAN Interface on Ethernet Router 1 and (and Ethernet Router 2) are different to the LAN interface on the Zyxel, ideally using 3 different networks [ but strictly speaking you can use the same ranges on the LAN interfaces of Ethernet Router 1 and 2 ].  I'd recommend
192.168.1.x netmask 255.255.255.0 for the Zyxel
10.1.1.x    netmask 255.255.255.0 for Ethernet Router 1
10.1.2.x    netmask 255.255.255.0 for Ethernet Router 2

In each case, the "gateway" (or LAN interface on the router should be X.X.X.1 or X.X.X.254 (for example 192.168.1.1 or 10.1.2.254)

An Ethernet router is quite a cheap device and I'd imagine you can pick them up for around $50.

Comment: and how does more than one router ensure that a computer on one won't be able to access a computer on the other?  just because there are different subnets within a network(which could even be configured on one router), doesn't necessarily mean that one cannot access the other.  Also, you misspelt zyxel in the beginning where you wrote "Internet | Xyxel ". And Zyxel are a company that make many devices. Perhaps you mean any router? or a specific one made by them with a specific feature? and as mentioned, it doesn't necessarily mean one subnet cannot access another.

Comment: @barlop - You may also want to revisit your jibes and take into account that my solution uses NAT to effectively provide firewalling without requiring lots of knowledge - I expect you know this is a bulk standard feature built into pretty much any router - which I refer to specifically in my post and which DOES prevent access from 1 subnet to the other when used in the configurations I provided - and with the limits I specifically stated  (and indeed showing 2 configurations using NAT differently for effect) .

Comment: Those aren't jibes. And now your'e clearer. What about the first solution you wrote.   Why did you write "(wan) Ethernet router" in the middle?  I know of two types of home router, one -a modem/router has a modem built in, the other(more dedicated router) has no modem built in and has a socket labelled WAN for a modem. I see no modem on either side of where you wrote that. "Internet | Xyxel | +--- New Network PC1 | +--- New Network PC 2.5 ... (You may need a switch for more ports) | +--- (wan) Ethernet Router | 8 Port Switch | +----- (lan) Printer | +--- (lan) Printer 2 | +----- (lan) Exi..."

Comment: I guess double NAT works by connecting a LAN into the WAN port. (no harm in clarity).